# running a root only execute process with non root id

Tags: linux, root, uid, setuid

well i just wanted to understand the setuid mechanism.so i wrote a C program (prog1) that triggers a bash (i used `system("/bin/sh")`  when executed & i set the setuid-bit for the executable (as root),So normally when its executed by another user,but not root,it sets the effective id of the running process to 0 (root id) but the real uid remains as it is (in my case 1000 for user test).

Now i wrote another executable (prog2) & i gave the execution permission only for root `-rwx------` .

I logged in as user 'test' & i executed 'prog1' so a bash has been introduced as intended,i executed the command 'id' & got the following result which was also intended :

```
uid=1000(test) gid=1001(test) euid=0(root)groups=1001(test),27(sudo)
```

as it shows the real uid is 1000 and effective uid id 0(root) that's exactly what setuid-bit does ....now i wanted to execute prog2 (only root can execute) & i was surprised that the execution succeeded & i could even read /etc/shadow ...is that not a security issue ??? ...i mean normally a root only read/write/execute program can never be read/written/executed by another user ?? ...so please can you give me some useful information about that ?!

Answer (score 1):

Under linux, the `fsuid` is consulted when checking file system permissions. If not set explicitly otherwise, this `fsuid` matches the `euid` of the process.

Indeed, almost every permission is checked against the effective user id (that's the reason why it's called *effective*). The real user id is used for example to check if a signal may be sent (so you can kill suid processes you started). Many shells also do something like `seteuid(getuid());` for enhanced security.